# SKShapeNodes Colliding with my SKPhysics body when I don't want to

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I am making a game where I have a ball created as an SKSpriteNode that is colliding with some PhysicsBodies I do not want to. Here is my ball:

```
orangeBall = OrangeBall(path: ballTrajectory, color: UIColor.orange, borderColor: UIColor.black)
    orangeBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Physics.PhysicsNumbers.ballRadius)
    orangeBall.position = Physics.PhysicsNumbers.ballRestPos
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionsChecker.Ball
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionsChecker.Frame | CollisionsChecker.Box | CollisionsChecker.Score
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionsChecker.Frame | CollisionsChecker.Box | CollisionsChecker.Score
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    addChild(orangeBall)
```

and I want it to detect that it has been in contact with this score physics body but not actually collide:

```
score = NetBoxes(path: scoreStationary, color: UIColor.red, borderColor: UIColor.red)
    score.position = Physics.PhysicsNumbers.scoreRest
    score.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    score.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionsChecker.Score
    score.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    score.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionsChecker.Ball
    score.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    score.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    addChild(score)
```

(circleOfRadius is only for testing purposes) Every time I try to check my collisions it seems to not output what I want it to do:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionsChecker.Ball && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionsChecker.Score || firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionsChecker.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionsChecker.Ball{
        print("Ball in hoop")
    }
```

Essentially, my orangeBall which is a SKSphapeNode always collide with my Score PhysicsBody.  It might also be that both physics bodies around my ball and score get into contact.  I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.  I was recreating a physicsBody for my orangeBall later in the code.  Forming another physicsBody around it making it collide with my other nodes!